# Alternate ways to write an element in $S_n$ as a finite product of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I understand the following forms, which are commonly discussed.

$(a)\ (12),(13), . . . , (1n)$

$(b)\ (12),(23),...,(n−1,n)$

$(c)\ (12),(12\dots n)$

My question is....are there other forms? Are there other ways to show that all permutations can be written as collection of a certain type of products?

Comment: In general, you should expect there to be lots of ways. Here's another example: take all 3-cycles together with a single 2-cycle. Can you phrase your question more precisely? What "certain types" are you looking for?

Comment: The canonical way to represent permutations is as product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Honestly, I don't know the other ways I am looking for. My professor is sometimes very vague and mentioned that I should be able to "show all permutations can be written as a collection of things." Well, like said, I understand the three ways above, but was wondering what other common ways should I be familiar with and able to prove?

Comment: From looking at your examples, I'm guessing that you're asking about sets that generate $S_n.$